# How to write a unit test for a range (let's say Percentage)?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

Imagine I have a class representing a percentage. This class provides self validation through exceptions by not allowing values less than 0 or greater than 100 respectively.

When following TDD the functionality of a method/class should be apparent from the test that are testing the part of the code. Should a test in this case include a range?

**Pseudocode:**

```
testNegativeValuesAreNotAccepted() {
    try {
        Percentage::withValue(Integer.random(Integer.MIN, -1));

        Assert.fail("Percentage MUST NOT accept negative values.");
    } catch (InvalidPercentageValue e) {
    }
}

testPercentageIsCreatedWithCorrectValue() {
    Integer value = Integer.random(0, 100);

    Percentage percentage = Percentage::withValue(Integer.random(0, 100));

    Assert.equals(true, value.equals(percentage.value()));
}

testValuesOver100AreNotAccepted() {
    try {
        Percentage::withValue(Integer.random(101, Integer.MAX));

        Assert.fail("Percentage MUST NOT accept values over 100.");
    } catch (InvalidPercentageValue e) {
    }
}
```

Would this give the developer of the `Percentage` class enough information for him to program the class? Is there perhaps too much information for them? How could this range problem be solved in a different way?

Comment: So you're writing the tests and someone else is *separately* implementing it? What do you mean *"too much information"*? Are the test names not sufficient context?

Comment: I'm not a fan of using 'random' in a test, because your test is not reproducible anymore, and you may end up with it sometimes failing, and sometimes working.  If testing the whole range is unfeasible, pick a few 'representative' values (minimum, midpoint, maximum) and work with those instead.

Comment: @Eternal21 That's my concern as well. The problem with picking some values is how many values should I actually pick to have a decent sample. So far we've usually been catching these errors at the code review level. Surely, this example is simple enough to exactly see an error. I am mostly interested in knowing whether there are some better solution how to make the boundaries clearer within the tests themselves.

Comment: @jonrsharpe It can happen a different person implements a class someone else had written a unit test for. Has happened to a team I was part of before. What I meant with *too much information* is that perhaps covering the entire unsupported range by using the random is not necessary and I should use just a few values of the invalid range instead - as Eternal21 has suggested - which is what I have been doing so far.

Comment: Since we seem to be talking about integers, test at least the endpoints (0 and 100) and just beyond the endpoints (-1 and 101).

Comment: If you are doing TDD, why do you have more than 1 test that makes the result RED? The second test should not have been written until the first test passed.

Comment: A little suggestion that might help you later with debugging if any of these tests fail Add to the log the value that caused the test to fail. `"Percentage MUST NOT accept negative values. Value received: -1"` (or similar)

Comment: What is the exact problem with the format of this question that it has been down voted?

Comment: @DavidPacker *"It can happen a different person implements a class someone else had written a unit test for."* If you're doing TDD (as you stated) this "other person" is your pairing partner and therefore sits next to you. In any other case you're **not** doing TDD...

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Isn't that extreme programming? :)

Comment: @DavidPacker *"Isn't that extreme programming?"* only if you do this in pairs...

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Only doing one test at a time is a completely pointless waste of time if you know what the next test is going to be and can easily code for several.

Comment: tests which use random numbers seem like a very bad idea to me. what if the function fails for value 67? you would get one fail that wouldnt repeat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to test a range, then inline some data for the test.  I'm using Xunit here, but similar techniques apply for other frameworks.

```
    [Theory]
    [InlineData(0)]
    [InlineData(20)]
    [InlineData(100)]
    public void HappyPathPercentage(int input)
    {
          //Arrange
          //Act
          //Assert
    }

    [Theory]
    [InlineData(-1)]
    [InlineData(101)]
    public void FailPathPercentage(int input)
    {
          //Arrange
          //Act
          //Assert
    }
```

Comment: much better than random numbers!!!